# OrientDB 2.2.4 Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, orientdb

I am trying to setup a cluster for load balancing. I am using the Java Graph API. In the [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Distributed-Configuration.html#load-balancing) there is this code:

```
final OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/demo");
factory.setConnectionStrategy(OStorageRemote.CONNECTION_STRATEGY.ROUND_ROBIN_CONNECT);
OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
```

I copied and pasted the code exactly like this and I get this compilation error

> "incompatible types: CONNECTION_STRATEGY cannot be converted to
>   String"

The only relevant import I have is:

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote;
```

Can you please help? 
Has anyone tried this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you try with OStorageRemote.CONNECTION_STRATEGY.ROUND_ROBIN_CONNECT.toString() ?

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroRota, no error now. I hope it also works like this (I'll find out as soon as I complete setting up the cluster).

Comment: Updated the docs by adding the `.toString()`, thanks for reporting it.

Comment: @ChrisB I put my comment as asnwer

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
OStorageRemote.CONNECTION_STRATEGY.ROUND_ROBIN_CONNECT.toString()
```

Hope it helps